# Limit of expectation of a function of sufficient statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $h$ be abounded differentiable function on $[0, \infty)$, vanishing at zero, $h(0)=0$. If $Z$ has a standard normal distribution, $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n \mathbb{E}[h(1/(n^2Z^2))].$$

---

Noticing that $h(1/x^2)$ is absolutely integrable, and that $Z^2$ is the sufficient statistics for exponential family $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, I was trying to relate this problem to calculating the cumulants of $Z^2$ by differential identities of the exponential family. However, I was stuck and not sure whether this is the intended way to solve this problem.

---

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Solutions using properties of exponential family are preferable, as this is an exercise on this topic.